# NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id=' for nil:NilClass): in the article controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement the functionality of creating a new article. However when I click the Submit button it gives me the following error.

```
Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-23 14:04:29 +0500
Processing by ArticlesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lbrD/8QZAlLuxVbw3vmRuKI20zkrckYut4nebyW5hLk6EFkODh4d0IAZ6yms2oRkWGqE3eWlUQwBUrfu1SiAnw==", "article"=>{"title"=>"AYYE", "text"=>"Ma ka "}, "commit"=>"Create Article"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id=' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:26:in `create'
```

Here's the `create` method:

```
def create
    @article.user_id = current_user.id
      if @article.create
         redirect_to @article
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
```

I am just starting out with RoR, hence unable to understand what's the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you `@article` is nil. It is throwing you error about calling/accessing `user_id` of `nil` object.

You need to make sure you define `@article` first, something like this

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  @article.user_id = current_user.id

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end      
end

private
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
end
```

Comment: `Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-23 20:45:56 +0500
Processing by ArticlesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KS6SEc7r+swxe1SKPs2d5gBnmCOKN3z6ewJJBGInf0MP/BHs1dyXMOnsFZxcd8ouDVbWJCKIbf8kvJm9EGqQ/A==", "article"=>{"title"=>"bappa", "text"=>"peeroun ko main manta hun"}, "commit"=>"Create Article"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
`

Comment: `Rendering articles/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered articles/_form.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered articles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 30.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)` I get this logged into my console. Plus no article is created and I don't get redirected.

Comment: @MuhammadTaha Are you setting other attributes of `@article`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of `Article` first. Then assign `user_id` and `save` the record.

```
def create
  @article = Article.new
  @article.user_id = current_user.id

  @article.save
  if @article.errors.any?
    # error handling
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: `/home/taha/blog/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:39: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' if @article erorrs.any? ^ /home/taha/blog/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:66: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: Typo. I forgot a dot at '@article.errors.any?'. Answer updated

Comment: `Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-23 20:51:20 +0500
Processing by ArticlesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KS6SEc7r+swxe1SKPs2d5gBnmCOKN3z6ewJJBGInf0MP/BHs1dyXMOnsFZxcd8ouDVbWJCKIbf8kvJm9EGqQ/A==", "article"=>{"title"=>"bappa", "text"=>"peeroun ko main manta hun"}, "commit"=>"Create Article"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
`

Comment: `No template found for ArticlesController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 82ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
` This is what I get now.

Comment: No redirection. No article creation.